# Error al restaurar copia de base de datos desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema de respaldo/restauracion de base de datos para mi proyecto. Hasta ahora he podido lograr respaldar la base de datos de mi sistemas sin problemas, pero no logro de ninguna manera poder hacer que se restaure desde el apartado de "Restaurar" que he hecho, y todo debido a la forma como se respalda la base de datos.

La base de datos me la esta respaldando con los datos de esta manera

```
    CREATE TABLE `citas` (
      `idCitas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `fCita` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `horaAtencion` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Examen_idExamen` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `nombreExamen` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Personas_cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
      `fechaSolicitud` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `idEstatus` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idCitas`),
      KEY `fk_Citas_Examen1_idx` (`Examen_idExamen`),
      KEY `fk_Citas_Personas1_idx` (`Personas_cedula`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Citas_Examen1` FOREIGN KEY (`Examen_idExamen`) REFERENCES `examen` (`idExamen`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Citas_Personas1` FOREIGN KEY (`Personas_cedula`) REFERENCES `personas` (`cedula`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

El problema esta es la parte donde comienza a mostrar la llave principal y la llave foranea simplemente porque la tabla citas es quien se esta creando primero que la tabla personas, y de tanto intentar, me fui a phpmyadmin a poner todo el sql a ver donde daba el error, y efectivamente es ahi diciendo lo siguiente:

> ## 1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint

Quisiera que al hacer el respaldo de la base de datos, la misma se guardase como lo hace phpmyadmin al momento de exportar las tablas: primero crea todas las tablas, luego los insert si existen y por ultimo la asignacion de llave foraneas y primarias. Como podria lograr eso? o como podria hacer para poder restaurar mi base de datos estando de esa manera?

Para respaldar, aplico el siguiente codigo

```
<?php
    //ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
    $mysqlUserName      = "root";
    $mysqlPassword      = "1234";
    $mysqlHostName      = "localhost";
    $DbName             = "dycasys";
    $backup_name        = "mdycasys.sql";
    $tables             = array("sesion", "personas", "tipousuario", "informes", "familiar", "examen", "estatuscita", "citas");

   //or add 5th parameter(array) of specific tables:    array("mytable1","mytable2","mytable3") for multiple tables

    Export_Database($mysqlHostName,$mysqlUserName,$mysqlPassword,$DbName,  $tables, $backup_name=false );

    function Export_Database($host,$user,$pass,$name,  $tables, $backup_name=false )
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);
        $mysqli->select_db($name);
        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $queryTables    = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row())
        {
            $target_tables[] = $row[0];
        }
        if($tables !== false)
        {
            $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables);
        }
        foreach($target_tables as $table)
        {
            $result         =   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $fields_amount  =   $result->field_count;
            $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;
            $res            =   $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
            $TableMLine     =   $res->fetch_row();
            $content        = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0)
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_row())
                { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                    if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )
                    {
                            $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                    $content .= "\n(";
                    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++)
                    {
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) );
                        if (isset($row[$j]))
                        {
                            $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $content .= '""';
                        }
                        if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                        {
                                $content.= ',';
                        }
                    }
                    $content .=")";
                    //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                    if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num)
                    {
                        $content .= ";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $content .= ",";
                    }
                    $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                }
            } $content .="\n\n\n";
        }
        //$backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').")__rand".rand(1,11111111).".sql";
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.".$date.sql";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\"");
        echo $content; exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿Te sirvió la respuesta? ¿Necesitas más información?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, ¿porque no usas directamente `mysqldump`?

Podrías hacer un comando en `linux` que exportase la `BBDD` directamente desde linea de comandos, así permites a `mysqldump` exportar correctamente la `BBDD` sin que tengas problemas para volver a recuperarla, te dejo un pequeño código para que veas como lo puedes hacer.

```
shell_exec("mysqldump --force --opt --verbose --compress --routines --result-file={$myDatabaseFile}.sql {$myDatabase} > /dev/null 2> {$myDatabaseLog}.log");
```

La función utilizada es: http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php

Con eso, exportas la BBDD en la ruta que quieras (`$myDatabaseFile`), tienes que tener en cuenta que en caso de que no exista un `.my.cnf` en la `home` del usuario que esté ejecutando `php`, tendrás que poner el `user/pass` de un usuario valido de `MySQL` que pueda hacer un dump de la `BBDD`.

Por ejemplo:

```
shell_exec("mysqldump -u pruebas -pmypass --force --opt --verbose --compress --routines --result-file={$myDatabaseFile}.sql {$myDatabase} > /dev/null 2> {$myDatabaseLog}.log");
```

También te dará un `log` en `$myDatabaseLog` de manera que si algo sale mal, lo puedes ver ahí.

Una vez tengas el backup en un directorio "publico" simplemente mandas al usuario a esa dirección y listo.

Para borrarlo un `cron` o una acción que lo haga a mano. Eso ya lo dejo a tu elección. Pero lo mejor es siempre usar una herramienta propia de `MySQL` como `mysqldump` porque él sabe como hacer correctamente el `dump` de la `BBDD` para que no tengas problemas al restaurar.